# Crontab Command Separate Line

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have two python scripts:

```
#1. getUrl.py # used to collect target urls which takes about 10 mins and used as the input for the next script
#2. monitoring.py # used to monitoring the website.

00 01 * * * /usr/bin/python /ephemeral/monitoring/getUrl.py > /ephemeral/monitoring/input && /usr/bin/python /ephemeral/monitoring/monitoring.py >> /ephemeral/monitoring/output
```

I put the this command in crontab and wondering how could I write that long command into two or three lines. Something like the python line separator example below but for Crontab command, so it is more readable:

```
>>> print \
... 'hel\
... llo'
helllo
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

No, you can't do that. From the man page:

> There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines,
>   like the shell's trailing "\".

You can put the commands in a script and run it.

Comment: Specifically, this information is found in `man 5 crontab`.